# Fetching all images from ABAddressBook crashes due to memory pressure

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, addressbook, abaddressbook

I'm querying all persons from the IOS address book and store their image in a local cache. Everything works fine for small address books - however a **lot of entries (>1000) crash the app** due to memory pressure.

After investigating the issue it seems that the `ABPersonCopyImageData` allocates memory for that image, and returns a `CFDataRef photoData` with a refcount of 2. After releasing the data `CFRelease(photoData)` the refcount stays at 1, which suggests that the `ABAddressBookRef addressBook` keeps a reference, probably for caching reasons. The memory consumption linearly increases through the whole loop.

After the loop `CFRelease(addressBook)` finally cleans up all references and frees up the memory. So one hack-ish solution is to periodically release the address book and create a new one (every 100 items or so), but it has some downsides.

Is there another way to tell the address book to release the reference to the image data?

```
- (void)testContacts {
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil);
    CFArrayRef allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for (CFIndex idx = 0; idx < nPeople; idx++ ) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allContacts, idx );

        if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
            CFDataRef photoData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
            if (photoData) {
                // do something (eg. store data) - does not affect problem

                CFRelease(photoData);
            }
        }
    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

Comment: does a manual handled autoreleasepool  maybe help? Have you checked with instruments of allocs happens without free`s ?

Comment: Autoreleaspool will not help (I am already releasing all relevant data manually), and free happens as soon as the addressBook is released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so far periodically releasing the `addressBook` seems to be the only solution to problem, see code below.

Releasing every 100 entries adds around **8% overhead on execution time**, but as expected **reduces the memory almost by a factor of 10** for 1000 phonebook entries (i.e 35MB and 15sec vs 4MB vs 16.2sec on an iPhone 4)

I hope anybody can come up with a better solution, until then I will use this.

```
void abImagesV3() {
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil);
    CFArrayRef allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for (CFIndex idx = 0; idx < nPeople; idx++ ) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allContacts, idx );

        if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
            CFDataRef photoData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
            if (photoData) {
                // do something (eg. store data) - does not affect problem
                CFRelease(photoData);
            }
        }

        if (idx%100 == 99) {
            CFRelease(addressBook);
            CFRelease(allContacts);
            addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil);
            allContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        }
    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that an `@autoreleasepool` will indeed help your case like Volker suggested in the comments.
Calling `CFRelease` doesn't actually free the memory, it just decreases the retain count of the object, like `release` would do before ARC.
So the memory usage is accumulated until the next drain of the autorelease pool which happens at the end of the current cycle of the current run-loop.

Also, please note that you can use toll-free bridging to transfer the ownership to ARC and make this even more efficient:

```
- (void)testContacts {
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil);
    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for (CFIndex idx = 0; idx < nPeople; idx++ ) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[idx];

            if (ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
                NSData *photoData = (__bridge_transfer NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
                if (photoData) {
                    // do something (eg. store data) - does not affect problem
                }
            }
        }
    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately memory behaviour is the same as in the original version. Memory increases linearly throughout the loop (from 6MB to 44MB peak for 1000 contacts), and drops down to 6MB after `CFRelease(addressBook)`. I really think that after requesting the image the `addressBook` retains a reference to the image for caching -  and is therefore not released in the `@autoreleasepool`